# How to read text from only a portion of the image with pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm trying to read the 213 from this image but i cant even get pytesseract to read everything
Here is my best effort code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('gamepictures/text.png')  # Load the image
img = cv2.cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert to grey
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 15)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 6')
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have been trying to change the treshholding algorithm i even tried with canny, but i can't get it to work.
So my questions are how can i read everything?

And how can i only read the 213

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpujb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('gamepictures/text.png')  # Load the image
img = img[98:190,6:149,:]
img = cv2.cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert to grey
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 3)
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, -2)

txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 10 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(img.shape)
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Basically I just sliced the image and played around with the parameters a bit. The GaussianBlur is there to make the image more continuous.

The `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789` is optional and just makes sure that only numbers are read.

Comment: I used the code and modified  the tessedit_char_whitelist to letters only, and i tried to read the name just above in the picture and it gave a string of random letters. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: In my case the name got extracted just fine even without blurring, whitelist and image slicing. Did you also change how the image is sliced? If you keep the same slicing as in my answer and change whitelist to letters only, it is expected that you get string of random letters, because that image slice contains only numbers and you order it to get some kind of letters from those numbers.